# Error `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable` when uploading file with `gcloud run jobs replace tmp.yaml`

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-sdk

Im running Google Cloud SDK 458.0.1 & core 2023.12.20 with python 3.11.4
Im calling the command on a file tmp.yaml which was downloaded with `gcloud run jobs describe <job name> --format export`
I am getting `ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`

The error (I think) is being caused by the lines

```
metadata:
  labels:
    run.googleapis.com/lastUpdatedTime: 2024-01-07T03:37:17.506925Z
```

however these lines are appended during execution of the replace command

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: We cannot help you with vendor bugs. Delete your post and repost it on Google's Issue Tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers Officially, Google does not monitor Stackoverflow bug reports. Google monitors the Issue Tracker and engineers are assigned problems from the Issue Tracker.